# Java Reflection , how to get newInstance with constructor is SomeObject.Class ex: Class<Customer> customerClass

Tags: java, reflection

I have the constructor

```
  public CustomerService(Class<Customer> clazz) {
    super(clazz);
}
```

So, I receive Class of the Customer in constructor, how can I get newInstance using reflection?

I have search here but I dind't found any solution

I have tried with no sucess

```
Object entityService =    Class.forName("CustomerService").getConstructor(Object.class).newInstance(customerObject);
```

Any Ideia?

Comment: `clazz.newInstance()`

Comment: Are you attempting to create a new instance of `Customer` or of `CustomerService` using reflection?

Comment: A need to create a new instance of CutomerService with Customer.class as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor's signature has parameter with `Class` type, not an `Object`.

```
Object entityService =    Class.forName("CustomerService").getConstructor(Class.class).newInstance(customerObject);
```

PS 
It seems (by name) that `customerObject`'s type is not a `Class`, but it should.

Comment: Did you mean use `Customer.class` instead of pasting the same code as OP?

Comment: @MiserableVariable The constructor accepts a `Class` argument. That's what you need to specify to the `getConstructor()` call.

Comment: OOps, I thought `customerObject` is an object of type `Customer`. Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @MiserableVariable Honestly, I don't know what OP meant it to be, but it has to be a `Class` (doesn't really look like it though).

Answer (score 0):

As Ph. Voronov said, worked, just changed

from

```
 newInstance(customerObject);
```

to

```
  Object entityService = Class.forName(sinpleClassName).getConstructor(Class.class).newInstance(customerObject.getClass());
```